# LEFT JOIN SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, left-join

I'm having problems when making a left join with SQLite.

structure of the tables

```
contacts: id_c, first_name, last_name, photo_link
messages: id_msg, id_sender, id_recipient, utimestamp, message, chatID
```

I'm doing a query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM messages m 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts c ON (c.id_c=m.id_sender) 
  WHERE m.chatID=26
```

This query returns values ​​from the message table.
But returns null for the contacts table.

I tried several ways and can not resolve this problem. Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't return NULLs? Please post three things: a) a few example rows in each table that demonstrate the problem b) the result of running the query when your tables contain only those example rows c) what you thought the result should be. Please also consider posting this information in a http://sqlfiddle.com to make it easier for us to test for ourselves.

Comment: I created an example in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f726e/2)
I did not know this site. Thanks for the suggestion.
It's working perfectly in this instance, but does not work the same way in Chrome developer Tools. What should be happening?

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in SQLite, sometimes it happens (an other `LEFT JOIN` related bug: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/73075

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved. Probably there was a bug. Once tested in SQL Fiddle, I realized that it worked without problems. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Returning nulls for the columns from the contacts table is exactly what I'd expect from a working LEFT JOIN in the case that there isn't a contact whose `id_c` matches the `id_sender` for `chatID` 26. Have you double-checked that you have such a contact in the `contacts` table?

Comment: I created an example in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f726e/2). It's working perfectly in this instance, but does not work the same way in Chrome developer Tools. What should be happening?